# Cannot import package in my android application

Tags: android, google-play-services

Im using google play services to create a turn based multiplayer game but I cannot import the following...

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.*;
```

I get an error saying it cannot be resolved, any ideas why?

Comment: are you import google-play-services correctly ??

Comment: @mohammedmomn I am not sure, I think I did it correctly because I am able to import **com.google.android.gms.games.realtime.*;**

Comment: could you check your version of google play services ?? i think com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased   in newer version

Comment: @mohammedmomn How can I check it?

Comment: the easiest way from  android sdk manager you can check if it need to to be updated or not

Comment: @mohammedmomn it says its up to date

Comment: i try to find any solution for this problem  , but i find google doc said there are steps to initialize the game client are you made it ? 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Comment: @mohammedmomn Yeah the library just has two classes, basegameactivity and gamehelper, I already have these two classes in my project and I reference them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When I added the library to my project, the path pointed to the wrong version of google play services which did not have turnbased class in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct dependency version in your `build.gradle`. It needs to be `4.1.+` to support turn-based.

```
dependencies {        
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
}
```